# how to convert from list of lists to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, key-value

Hi :) I have this table and I need to convert it into a dictionary where the firsl line are the keys and then each value from the rest of the tables will be values but iterating through them each at the time . I have this table :

```
my_table = [["Account Manager", "Name", "BP", "Contact", "Quote Name", "Type", "Status", "Total"],
            ["bubble", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["rose", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["purple", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["dark", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["star", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
            ["asmr", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],]
```

This is the code used to iterate through it :

```
dict_from_table = {}
for position, key in enumerate(my_table[0]):
  dict_from_table[key] = []
  for value_row in my_table[1:2]:
    dict_from_table[key].append(value_row[position])

print(dict_from_table)
```

And this is the output that comes from it :

```
{'Account Manager': ['bubble'], 'Name': ['kwlak'], 'BP': ['5677'], 'Contact': ['conn'], 'Quote Name': ['987'], 'Type': ['butter'], 'Status': ['fish'], 'Total': ['fill']}
```

I need it to go through all the lists and return each value once for the keys (Account manager , name , etc.) but also I do not want it to return the value as a list I want it to be in the same dictionary as the keys. Do I need another for loop ?

Comment: You need to return it as a list because each key needs to be unique

Comment: First list in `my_table` has 8 elements, but other lists have 10 elements. So you can not use first list as keys for other list elements.

Comment: And you will run into an `IndexError` as suggested by Mohammed Khoshbin

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to 'transpose' the table (switch rows and columns):

```
output = {column[0]: column[1:] for column in zip(*my_table)}
```

(Or use `list(column[1:])` if you need a list instead of tuple.)

However if you are doing a lot of manipulation on table data, consider using `pandas`. You can create a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(my_table[1:], columns=my_table[0])
```

then export it back to a dict of lists like this:

```
output = df.to_dict("list")
```

(You will need to make sure there are the same number of column headings as cells in each row first.)

Answer (score 1):

You are nested loop is inverted. Since your keys are fixed, build an empty dictionary from those keys with empty lists as values:

```
In [7]: my_table = [["Account Manager", "Name", "BP", "Contact", "Quote Name", "Type", "Status", "Total"],
   ...:             ["bubble", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
   ...:             ["rose", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
   ...:             ["purple", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
   ...:             ["dark", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
   ...:             ["star", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],
   ...:             ["asmr", "kwlak", "5677", "conn", "987", "butter", "fish", "fill", "stat", "total"],]
   ...:

In [8]: keys = my_table[0]

In [9]: result = {k:[] for k in keys}
```

Then loop over the rest of the table:

```
In [10]: for row in my_table[1:]:
    ...:     for k,v in zip(keys, row):
    ...:         result[k].append(v)
    ...:

In [11]: result
Out[11]:
{'Account Manager': ['bubble', 'rose', 'purple', 'dark', 'star', 'asmr'],
 'Name': ['kwlak', 'kwlak', 'kwlak', 'kwlak', 'kwlak', 'kwlak'],
 'BP': ['5677', '5677', '5677', '5677', '5677', '5677'],
 'Contact': ['conn', 'conn', 'conn', 'conn', 'conn', 'conn'],
 'Quote Name': ['987', '987', '987', '987', '987', '987'],
 'Type': ['butter', 'butter', 'butter', 'butter', 'butter', 'butter'],
 'Status': ['fish', 'fish', 'fish', 'fish', 'fish', 'fish'],
 'Total': ['fill', 'fill', 'fill', 'fill', 'fill', 'fill']}
```

Although note, this assumes that your keys in the first row line up with the rest... the example data does not have that, but I assume this is just a transcription error.

Comment: ok understood but can I get each key to have the value once at one iteration like this : {'Account Manager': 'bubble',  'Name': 'kwlak',  'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill', 'Account Manager': 'rose',  'Name': 'kwlak',  'BP': '5677', 'Contact': 'conn', 'Quote Name': '987', 'Type': 'butter', 'Status': 'fish', 'Total': 'fill', }  and so on for each value

Comment: @Andy no, dictionary keys must be *unique*

Comment: oh right I keep overlooking that ...

Comment: does it gets easier ? will I come to a moment when I will think these are easy :) ?

Comment: @Andy with practice, sure. Once you see the same sort of problem multiple times you'll know how to approach it the next time you see it.